# PHP Regular expression to get words with repeated chars in a string

Tags: php, regex, words, chars

I'm trying to get the words in a string with repeated chars.
For example: "II loooovve this video. It's awesooooommeee."

How can I get the result:
loooovve
awesooooommeee
?

Comment: Try this: `.*([a-z])\\1{2,}.*` (starts matching if 3 repeated letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with a back-reference:

```
\b\w*(\w)\1\w*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cV4tO6/6)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b     # word boundary
\w*    # match 0 or more word characters
(\w)   # match a single word char and capture it as group #1
\1     # back-reference to captured group #1 to make sure we have a *repeat*
\w*    # match 0 or more word characters
```

btw it will also match `II` since it has a repeating character `I`.

Comment: It's not working... it match for example word: _vidieo_ (two __i__ letters)

Comment: If you want consecutive repeats then check my updated answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern for matching all words with 3+ repeated letters:

```
\b\w*(\w)\1{2}\w*
```

II **loooovve** this video. It's **awesooooommeee**.

---

https://regex101.com/r/cP7kT7/1